# How to subract two dates with 2019-12-17T23:42:20Z this format in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have tried using,

```
Timetaken= 2019-12-18T23:10:45Z - 2019-12-17T23:42:20Z
```

The output is 84505.0

I need output as 23 hours

Comment: Similarly, 2019-12-20T12:11:37Z "2019-12-20T09:04:39Z"is 11218.0. I need as 3 hours

Comment: There's better ways to do this than this, by converting to Dates. But an easy solution would be to use your output which is in seconds, dividing it by 3600 and rounding...

Comment: I can see hours now.. Thank you.. whats the other way?

Comment: That's definitely not your code. a) that code will not run b) that code will not produce output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the hours from this method:

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime("2019-12-20T12:11:37Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
d2 = datetime.strptime("2019-12-20T09:04:39Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

print(round((d1-d2).seconds / 3600))
```